# Play Framework: Multi Module Project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator

I have created a multi module project with the following structure:

```
my_app  
|__app  
|__conf  
|__public  
|__project  
|  |__CommonBuild.scala  
|__core  
|  |__src/main/scala  
|  |__src/test/scala      
|  |__build.sbt  
|__build.sbt
```

I notice 2 issues:

1. In development mode when I do `activator run` and I make changes to my `core` module I see that it recompiles but when running it is picking up published `core-[ver].jar` dependency instead of the module locally.
2. In IntelliJ IDEA, I see the same issue. Under project structure of `my_app` I do see core added as both a module and a jar.

`CommonBuild.scala`:

```
object CommonBuild {
  val settings: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
     organization = "com.myorg",
     scalaVersion = "2.11.8",
     transitiveClassifiers in Global := Seq(Artifact.SourceClassifier),
     resolvers ++= Seq(
         "scalaz-bintray" at "https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
     ),
     aggregate in update := false,
     parallelExecution in Test := false,
     Keys.fork in Test := false,
     libraryDependencies ++= Seq(/*all dependencies here*/)
  )
}
```

`core/build.sbt`:

```
name := "core"

CommonBuild.settings

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "src" / "main" / "resources"

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Test += baseDirectory.value / "src" / "test" / "resources"

publishMavenStyle := true

publishArtifact in Test := true
```

`my_app/build.sbt`:

```
CommonBuild.settings

lazy val my_app =
  (project in file(".")).
    enablePlugins(PlayScala)
    .aggregate(core)
    .dependsOn(core % "test->test;compile->compile")

lazy val core = project

name := "my-app"

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

If I do not `publish` or `publishLocal` the `core` artifact, `my_app` does not pick up the `core` module to compile and throws a bunch of compilation errors.

How do I make sure that both activator and IntelliJ IDEA use core module itself as the dependency instead of the artifact produced by it?

Comment: Have you read the docs about sub projects? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SBTSubProjects#Working-with-sub-projects

Comment: @marcospereira Yes, I created my multi module project by following the instructions in that page.